# How to find the real path when I create a file manually into a Directory

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm into a trouble, I've got a Directory and a FileSystemWatcher that controls the files that are moved and created there, I have to CheckSum them and this is fine when I move the file, but when I try to create a new text document and I give it a name, the program take as path the "...\new text document.txt" instead of the name that I give to it, how can I resolve this?

```
    private void watch()
    {

        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |                                                                        NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                    | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nuovo file creato", "My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);            
        string creato = e.FullPath;
        string cod = CheckSum(creato);
    }

    private string CheckSum(string fpath)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fpath))
            {
                return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's the default Windows Explorer gives the file before offering you the option to rename it: try creating a file with a tool that doesn't start with a placeholder name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, well I already thought about that but I'm too lazy and I think that it's a low efficiency solution... But if I'm obliged to do that I'll do! I'm still open to other suggestions B)